# How can I check if the next checkbox is checked?

Tags: html, jquery, razor

I am attempting to find out if the next checkbox on the onclick event is checked or not. If the next checkbox is checked, I want the background color to be White. Picture 1 shows the Yellow background for an unchecked row and a White background for a checked row. Picture 2 shows when I check the Yellow row, the next row changes to Yellow, I want it to remain White if it is already checked.

Is there a next function that I can use? Here is the code I have so far:

```
$('input[id="chkRow"]').on('change', (function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "white");
                $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css("background-color", "yellow");
            }
            else {
                $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "yellow");
                $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css("background-color", "white");
            }
        }));
```

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: It looks like you're using the same id chkRow for both checkboxes. If so, your HTML isn't valid as ids have to be unique. Just change the ids to classes instead.

Comment: I should have mentioned this was on a Razor page and these checkboxes are built based on a data field. I have the id set to chkRow for all of those. The function I have right now works great besides when the next checkbox is checked.

Comment: Fix the IDs. We've heard all the excuses, and none are valid. You'll cause problems for yourself and anyone else working on your project.

Comment: I changed the ids to classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of the current TD, and use that to find the corresponding cell in the next row, and then check whether the box is checked.

```js
$('input[id="chkRow"]').on('change', function() {
  var curRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var nextRow = curRow.next("tr");
  if (this.checked) {
    curRow.css("background-color", "white");
    var thisColumn = $(this).closest("td").index();
    if (nextRow.children("td").eq(thisColumn).find(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      nextRow.css("background-color", "white");
    } else {
      nextRow.css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  } else {
    curRow.css("background-color", "yellow");
    nextRow.css("background-color", "white");
  }
});
```